# Performance of inner join query for certain condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one question about inner join query in SQL Server 2008. Is there any situation where NOT to use inner joins.
I have one scenario please tell me that here inner join is fruitful or not.

I have 2 tables

- Table1 Columns: T1Id, Code and Name1, (Here Code is unique column)
- Table2 Columns: T2Id, T1id(reference from Table 1), Name2, Type

Now there can be millions of records in both table. Now user pass the Code and I have to search the Name2 3 times in same procedure for diff condition.
I can do it with 2 scenario.

**Scenario 1**

I can store T1Id in temp variable

```
Declare @Id Int
Select @Id=Top 1 T1Id from Table1 Where Code='ABC'
```

Step 2: I will write all my queries

```
Select Name2 From Table2 Where T1id=@Id and Type='A'
Select Name2 From Table2 Where T1id=@Id and Type='B'
Select Name2 From Table2 Where T1id=@Id and Type='C'
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
Select Name2 
from Table2 Inner join Table1 on Table1.T1Id = Table2.T1Id
Where Table2.Type='A' and Table1.Code='ABC'

Select Name2 
From Table2 Inner join Table1 on Table1.T1Id = Table2.T1Id
Where Table2.Type='B' and Table1.Code='ABC'

Select Name2 
From Table2 Inner join Table1 on Table1.T1Id = Table2.T1Id
Where Table2.Type='C' and Table1.Code='ABC'
```

Please tell me which one is good to use. Both tables can have more than millions records in future.

Comment: Do  you need to run 3 queries?

Answer (score 3):

Run one query, make sure you have good indexes

```
Select Name2 
From Table2 Inner join Table1 on Table1.T1ITable2.T1Id
Where Table2.Type IN ('A', 'B', 'C') and Table1.Code='ABC'
```

A graphical query plan will show where you need indexes

A million rows isn't much and well within capability of SQL Server

Comment: As @gbn said, good indexing will make either solution work well. Just use the simplest one (the join).